# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widgets'

Tags: python, django

I am getting error when I write `forms.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm, UsernameField
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1= forms.CharField(label='password',widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password2= forms.CharField(label='Confirm password(again)',widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

The server says:

```
   username= UsernameField(label='username',widgets=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus':True,'class':'form-control bg-success'}))
  File "C:\Users\ITS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 216, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widgets'
```

But when I write widgets in meta class:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username= UsernameField(label='username')
    password= forms.CharField(label=('password'),strip=False)
    class Meta:
        widgets={
            'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus':True,'class':'form-control'}),
            'password':forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'current-password','class':'form-control'}),

        }
```

the server totally works but form control class does not in the HTML page.

HTML code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <h3 class="text-white my-5"> Login Page</h3>
  <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for fm in form %}
    <div class="">
      {{fm.label_tag}}{{fm}}<small class="text-warning">{{fm.errors| striptags}}</small>

    </div>
    {% endfor %}<br>
    <input type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary" value="Login">
    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}<br>
    <p class="alert alert-danger my-3">{{ error}}</p>
    
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock  %}
```

Help me with this please.

Comment: The error is part of a form with `username= UsernameField(`. This is not the form you shared in your question.

Answer (score 0):

look like by mistake you use widgets instead of widget in the form try below changes :-

```
username= UsernameField(label='username', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus':True,'class':'form-control bg-success'}))
```

This is defined in here :- https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L66